# Showing that $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\tan x}{1+e^x}\,dx$ diverges.

Tags: improper-integrals, divergent-integrals

I want to show that the improper integral $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\tan x}{1+e^x}\,dx$ diverges. I know that from $0$ to $\pi/2$  the following inequalities hold:

\begin{align*}
\frac{\tan x}{1+e^x}&<\frac{\tan x}{2e^x}\\
\frac{\tan x}{1+e^x}&<\frac{x}{2e^x}
\end{align*}

But I can't use them to show the integral diverges. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Note $\frac{1}{1+e^x}>\frac{1}{1+e^{\pi/2}}$ for any $x$ in the interval $\left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$.

Comment: What you really want is a lower bound on $\tan(\pi/2 - x)$ when $x$ is small.

Comment: This integral is convergent, it gives a value as 6.61066 by NIntegrate.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_0^{π/2}\frac{\tan x}{1+e^x}\rm dx\ge\frac1{1+e^{π/2}}\int_0^{π/2}\tan x\rm dx$$ and the right hand side integral diverges.